# Select Maximum Value of Auto-Increment Primary Key Using Python/MySQL

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

I can now do Adds/Deletes/Updates to my MySQL database using a Python interface without problem. However I have got bogged down in trying to find the maximum value of an integer auto-increment primary key. I need the value to add it immediately to another table to create a join for future queries. Thank you in anticipation for the elucidation to this.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(id_col_name) FROM tblName
```